# Batch script: Search two strings in log file and store values in variable

Tags: batch-file

**Requirement:**
I have to search text "The connection to the remote server can not be established." in complete log file and get the value of "Outgoing Message Key, eg 778445628, 778439775 in a varaible as comma (,) seperated value so that I can use the varaible's values to insert into a database table.

**Note:** 
1) I cannot directly serach "Outgoing Message Key" because message key value comes in another scenario as well and i want "message key" value only for network error.
2) Log file contents are in XML format so XML tags are in log file.

Please let me know if I am not clear here.
I have to implement solution in batch script.
Please assist ASAP.
Thanks in advance.

Please find below my sample input log file content:

```
Date Time: 2015-03-10 07:00:29

Server Name: abcde

Agent ID: 23

User Name: user

Message In: W6BFAssignmentEvents_OnAfterDelete event fired

Message Out:

Date Time: 2015-03-10 07:00:31

Server Name: abcde

Agent ID: 12

User Name: user

Error Number: -1

Error Description: <MessageResult Status="2"><Source>System</Source>
<Description>The connection to the remote server can not be established.</Description><Line>0</Line></MessageResult>

Error Source: W6IntUtilsLibGW.caer.ProcessPendingMessages

Outgoing Message Key: 778445628

Incoming Message:

Date Time: 2014-03-10 07:40:17

Server Name: abcde

Agent ID: 12

User Name: user

Error Number: -1

Error Description: <MessageResult Status="2"><Source>System</Source>

<Description>The connection to the remote server can not be established.</Description><Line>0</Line></MessageResult>

Error Source: W6IntUtilsLibGW.caer.ProcessPendingMessages

Outgoing Message Key: 778439775

Incoming Message:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like the idea of creating a variable with a comma delimited list of keys, but here you go.

**Pure batch**

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "noConnection="
set "keys="
for /f "tokens=1,4" %%A in (
  'findstr /r /c:"The connection to the remote server can not be established\." /c:"^Outgoing Message Key: " input.log'
) do (
  if %%A equ Outgoing (
    if defined noConnection set "keys=!keys!,%%B"
    set "noConnection="
  ) else set noConnection=1
)
set "keys=!keys:~1!"
echo !keys!
```

**Using my hybrid JScript/batch [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) utility**

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "keys="
for /f %%A in (
  'jrepl "The connection to the remote server can not be established\.[\s\S]*?^Outgoing Message Key: (\d+)" "$1" /m /jmatch /f input.log'
) do set "keys=!keys!,%%A"
set "keys=!keys:~1!"
echo !keys!
```

or

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f %%A in (
  'jrepl "The connection to the remote server can not be established\.[\s\S]*?^Outgoing Message Key: (\d+)"^
         "keys+=','+$1;false" /m /jmatch /jbeg "var keys=''" /jend "output.WriteLine(keys.slice(1))" /f input.log'
) do set "keys=%%A"
echo %keys%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dbenham for "Pure Batch" solution but some how I am getting syntax error while running this. Further assistance will be highly appreciated. And if possible please explain solution.

Comment: The only diff in your suggestion and my implementation is, I am using log file path as below:                                                                            for /f "tokens=1,4" %%A in ('findstr /r /c:"The connection to the remote server can not be established\." /c:"^Outgoing Message Key: " "E:\MyFolder\Log Files\testlog.txt" ')
)

Comment: I am running batch script on Windows 2008 R2

Comment: @Saurabh - I've tested all three codes, and they run perfectly. The code in your comment has an extra right parenthesis at the end. Also, the `do (` must appear on the same line, after the one good right parenthesis.

Comment: After correcting error now output is coming as ~1. What I am doing wrong here: @echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
Set "keys="
Set "noConnection="
 
for /f "tokens=1-4" %%A in ('findstr /i /c:"The connection to the remote server can not be established\." /c:"^Outgoing Message Key: " "E:\MyFolder\Log Files\testlog.txt"') do (
if %%A equ Outgoing (
                if defined noConnection set "keys=!keys!,%%B"
                set "noConnection="
                ) else set noConnection=1
)
set "keys=!keys:~1!"
echo %keys%

Comment: Even echo !keys! also printing ~1

Comment: @Saurabh - Your FOR /F should have `"tokens=1,4"`, not `"tokens=1-4"`. Also your FINDSTR is missing the `/R` option. You must be more diligent when transcribing code - every keystroke matters!

Comment: I am sorry for making such silly mistake :( Thanks a ton, now it is working as expected.  All your assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: @Saurabh - Don't forget to accept a good answer if it fully satisfies your needs.